# Программно узнать к какому порту подключена arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, com-порт

Пока что получается получить только список занятых портов (`COM1`, `COM3`, `COM5`), я знаю, что ардуино в 5 порту, но не могу быть в этом уверен. Может можно какой - нибудь `DeviceID` получить?

Пока что, за неимением других альтернатив, думаю подключаться ко всем доступным портам и читать получаемые значения, если вернёт то, что мне надо, значит это нужный порт, но это такое себе решение.

Comment: Через VID/PID скорее всего задача решится, но только COM-порты ничего о VID/PID не знают. Надо искать как для конкретного USB-порта узнать какой на нем COM висит.

Comment: Если устройство подключается через USB как виртуальный ком-порт, то никаких проблем - открываете диспетчер устройств, смотрите свойства нужного порта, выписываете оттуда VID/PID устройства. В дальнейшем в программной реализации ищете устройство по известным VID/PID. Если же это стандартный COM-порт, то у него никаких идентификаторов, кроме номера порта, нет.

Answer (score 2):

В среде "Arduino IDE" есть кнопка Tools -> Get Board Info она дает информацию по подключенному девайсу (название "Arduino" платы в вашем случае). Делает это она сверяя VID и PID с онлайн списками как я понимаю. 
**Update**: Пройдите по ссылке я там добавил ответ с описанием кода на c/c++.
Вот ссылка на подобный вопрос и ответ на него на англ. [Arduino Get Board Info](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39137/how-does-arduino-ide-get-board-info/39167)

Comment: Мне это надо сделать средствами С / С++, а не через Arduino IDE

Comment: Пройдите по ссылке, там есть готовый код на C# (они очень похожи с C++) уверен, вы разберётесь.